# Ranking based on 4 columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, ranking

i am working on my database in excel...I need to rank the Scorers by considering 4 league scores.I want Ranking based on Scores of leagues with priority from 1 to 4 i.e. who scored most in league 1 would be 1st and if same score in league 1 then consider league 2 scores and so on...my table is as following-
please if u know help me for ranking for my table...

..........A............B...............C................D..................E..............F

======= ======= ======= ======= ================

1.......ID......Score 1......Score 2......Score 3......Score 4......Rank

2...... N01.... 12...............   4.................  3................   18
3...... N02.... 15...............   4.................  6................   13
4...... N03.... 12...............   5.................  4................   11
5...... N04.... 12...............   4.................  3................   3
6...... N05.... 15...............   5.................  5................   8
7...... N06.... 16...............   3.................  2................   3
8...... N07.... 12...............   4.................  5................   12
9...... N08.... 10...............   5.................  4................   9
10.....N09....  13...............   6.................  4................   17
11.....N10....  10...............   5.................  4................   5

For ranking based on 2 fields i have used these formulas:

intermidiate total in  F2 to F11 -

=RANK(B2,B$2:B$11,0)+SUMPRODUCT((B2=B$2:B$11)*(C2

and The Rank in G2 -
=RANK(F2,F$2:F$11,1)

But I cannot do it for ranking based on 4 columns...Help plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course the easiest way to do this is simply to do `Data` > `Sort` and do 4 levels of sorting (Score1, ..., Score4), but I kinda liked this question to see if I could do it with formulas - A fun challenge...

The nicest way I could think of doing it without VBA would be to add in a few helper columns.

To do this, put the following formulas in:

```
F2: =B2
G2: =F2 & " - " & SUM(IF(B2=B$2:B$11,IF(C2>=C$2:C$11,1,0)))
```

And enter `G2` as an array formula using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Then, drag `G2` across till `I2` and then, just fill Columns `F:I` down for your dataset.

Now, if you sort based upon column `I`, you will have the data ordered as you want it.

---

Of course, you could make it all in one large and ugly formula in one cell per row:

```
=B2& " - " & SUM(IF(B2=B$2:B$11,IF(C2>=C$2:C$11,1,0)))& " - " & SUM(IF(C2=C$2:C$11,IF(D2>=D$2:D$11,1,0)))& " - " & SUM(IF(D2=D$2:D$11,IF(E2>=E$2:E$11,1,0)))
```

but this seems to be a better solution IMHO.

---

Hope this does the trick!

---

**EDIT:**

In response to your comment below, to get the rank, you'll need 2 extra columns (boy, this is getting long :p)...

Put in the following:

```
J2: =SUMPRODUCT((I2>=$I$2:$I$11)+0)+1
K2: =RANK(J2,$J$2:$J$11,1)+COUNTIF($J$2:OFFSET(J2,0,0),J2)-1
```

This will give you the rank using non-numeric data.

Hope this fully satisfies your criteria, but it's pretty ugly for sure... Like I said, I enjoyed the challenge of this, but the better way would be to just create a VBA function that took care of this for you...

Comment: Of course, your trick works !

But my need is to give Ranks _without_ _changing_ _the_ _order_ of ID and RANK formula works on number data type only.
So, please do if it can be.

Thanks for the above solution.

Comment: @PavanV, I updated my solution with your last request... Like I said, it's ugly, but was fun to try and figure out... Hope it does the trick!

Comment: Thanks John...its done as my requirement.Although its lengthy but the aim has been fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the scores will be bounded (e.g. always below 100) you can calculate a weighted score like

```
WEIGHTED_SCORE = (((SCORE1*100) + SCORE2)*100 + SCORE3)*100 + SCORE4
               = SCORE1*100^3 + SCORE2*100^2 + SCORE3*100 + SCORE4
```

Then rank based on the weighted score